# How can I show the whole line when I print?

Tags: python, printing

Good day,

I have copied and pasted the example code at this link:

https://ancell.in/capytaine/latest/user_manual/cookbook.html#simulation-with-several-bodies

My problem is that when I print the data, for each line, I can see the first characters, and after them, I only see dots rather than the real data.

For example, one of the printed lines is:

diffraction_force    (omega, wave_direction, influenced_dof) complex128 (...

i.e. I see the 3 dots rather than the value of the force.

Could you help me fixing this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Print uses the `__str__` method of the objects it gets, so one solution would be to create a subclass with your own version of `__str__`.

Alternatively you can check if the existing `__repr__` method produces your desired result by doing `print(repr(data))`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it has not worked: i still see the same output. Any more suggestion?